# Obtaining File path when storing image

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to obtain the filepath of my stored Image that's stored like so after using the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");


        mImageOne.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        SaveImageOne(imageBitmap);

}
```

SaveImageFunction

```
private void SaveImageOne(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image-1.jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This way I can store this 'filepath' of the stored File to SharedPreferences to be accessed later on and say passed into the ACTION_SEND as an image attachment.

Answer (score 0):

after this line `out.close();` write this line

```
String pathString = file.getAbsolutePath(); // gives you the path of the file
```

now use it how you want it

Comment: How would I go about using that pathString in this:

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Myimage.jpeg")); ?  Would I do: 

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///" + pathString)); or something similar?

Comment: yes have you tried it?  another long way too is `emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(new File(pathString)));` hope it solves it? if there are errors let me know @Shaniqua